# Is it possible to lift a SailsJS app synchronously?

Tags: sails.js

It would be handy for ***testing***.

It would ***avoid the boilerplate*** of having to lift the app on every spec.

My current code:

```js
beforeEach(function(done) {
  Sails.lift({ log: { level: 'error' } }, function(err, sails) {
    app = sails.express.app
    // beforeEach related stuff
    done()
  })
}
```

I want to put on my `specs_global.js`:

```
app = Sails.lift({ log: { level: 'error' } }).express.app
```

EDIT:

#### My problem to beign unable to lift Sails syncronously

The problem is that I want to **instanteate Sails** only once for **all** my specs, as it is an **expensive task** and I want my integration specs to run as **fast** as possible. Also I want to avoid the **boilerplate of calling Sails lift** on each of my specs files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `sails.load` and `sails.lift` are both asynchronous.  You're doing the right thing in your test (just make sure you call `sails.lower` in your `afterEach` method).  Take a look at the [current Sails integration tests](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/tree/master/test/integration) for an example of how we do it.  Also keep in mind that you might not need to `lift` and `lower` before each individual test--in some cases it might be okay to just lift once before a suite runs and use that instance for all the tests.  In that case, you can use `before` and `after` instead of `beforeEach` and `afterEach`.

Comment: Thanks! I was getting strange errors (like `Uncaught Error: Callback was already called.`) before adding sails.lower on `afterEach`

Answer (score 1):

Put this snippet in your `specs_global.js`:

```js
global.liftSails = function (cb) {
    // lift sails no more than once
    if (!global.app) {
        Sails.lift({ log: { level: 'error' } }, function(err, sails) {
            global.sails = sails;
            global.app = sails.express.app;
            cb();
        });
    } else {
        cb();
    }
}
```

Now you have `sails`and `app` available globally.

In your tests you can write something like this:

```js
beforeEach(function(done) {
    liftSails(function () {

        // do something with sails and app here

        done();
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks! cool snippet, I didn't know about the existence of the `global` variable!

Comment: I just realized this also prevents Sails being lifted more than once, because of the `global.app` condition. Great!

Answer (score 1):

Edy's answer solves the problem I had, but as I currently like using promises and I think they are a good fit here to avoid boilerplate, here is my solution using promises

#### My solution (using promises)

As I'm using promises ([q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) module) both on my code and on my specs, I took advantage of it. What I've done:

- load `globals.js` file before loading my specs
- on `globals.js` declare a global variable to be **a promise that Sails will lift**.

  ```js
  global.sails_lift_promise = liftSails()

  function liftSails() {
    return Q.ninvoke(Sails, 'lift', { log: { level: 'error' } })
            .then(function(_sails) {
              global.sails = _sails
              global.app = _sails.express.app
            })
  }
  ```
- this `sails_lift_promise` promise will lift Sails **only once** and will be available through all specs, so we can use it:

  ```js
  //on some_spec1.js
  beforeEach(function(done) {
    sails_lift_promise.then(doSomething).done(done)
  })
  //on some_spec2.js
  beforeEach(function(done) {
    sails_lift_promise.then(doAnotherThing).done(done)
  })
  ```